# How to return DataFrame with added column for numpy.average?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to create a new column in my dataframe that containing average data for the preceding column. My dataframe that I'm using is pretty large (GDP over 10 years), so I'll miniaturise it into as follows.

This is my original dataframe:

```
[In 1]: import pandas as pd
[In 2]: import numpy as np

[In 3]: original = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

[Out 3]:
   2006 2007 2008 
0    1    2    3  
1    1    3    5  
2    4    6    8
```

My intended dataframe:

```
   2006 2007 2008  avg
0    1    2    3   2.0
1    1    3    5   3.0
2    4    6    8   6.0
```

The current code I wrote so far looks like the following:

```
[In 4]: def avg(df):
            data = df[['2006', '2007', '2008']]
            df['avg'] = np.average(data)
            return df

        original.apply(avg, axis = 1)
```

But after running it, I received the following error:

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'", 'occurred at index China')
```

The thing is, in my code after [In 4], if I had changed np.average to np.max or np.min, a resulting DataFrame would have been created that would follow the format of my intended code output, with the right max/min values. So this error definitely has something to do with np.average function itself.

My questions are:

1. What's actually behind this AttributeError?
2. How should I create a new DataFrame column for numpy.average?

p.s. this is my first question, so if the formatting is a little weird, i'm sorry. do advise if you see any way I can improve in asking!

Answer (score 3):

You should directly do it with pandas:

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```